# AWS Lambda - How to stop retries when there is a failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know that when a Lambda function fails (for example when there is a time out), it tries to run the function 3 more times again. Is there any way to avoid this behavior? I' have been reading the documentation, but didn't find anyting about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't surface any failures to Lambda (handle them yourself) and don't timeout (you can get the time remaining from the context object).

Comment: You can do this in Python. boto3 provides a way for advanced configuration of boto3 clients. Refer this link: https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html. You can set retries to 0 like this: `client = boto3.client('ec2', config=Config(retries=dict(max_attempts=0)))`

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 Your solution does not address this problem. "'max_attempts' -- An integer representing the maximum number of retry attempts that will be made on a single request" this is merely for the lambda client

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDITED**: It's now possible to change the lambda settings to disable retries (see [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/?nc1=h_ls))

---

**Original answer**:

There isn't a way to disable retry behavior of Lambda functions.
I suggest two options to deal with that:

1. Make your Lambda able to handle retry cases correctly. You can use context.AwsRequestId (or corresponding field) that will be the same when a Lambda is retried.
2. Put your Lambda inside a state machine (using AWS Step Functions). You can only then disable retries.
   [This blog post](https://epsagon.com/blog/how-to-handle-aws-lambda-errors-like-a-pro) I've written gives a more general explanation.

Comment: What is the logic that AWS is not changing this behavior it or not making is configurable and can be disabled?  Besides making extra money. lol

Comment: Other option would push the requestid to dynamodb and then check against that if it is a retry or a new invocation. Again more money for AWS. lol

Comment: How can one disable retries if Lambda is invoked from StepFucntions? I have a Lambda Step that retries.

Answer (score 32):

It retries when it is an *unhandled failure* (an error that you didn't catch) or if you handled it but still told Lambda to retry (e.g. in Node, when you call `callback()` with a non-null first argument).

To stop it from retrying, you should make sure that any error is handled and you tell Lambda that your invocation finished successfully by returning a non-error (or in Node, calling `callback(null, <any>)`.

To do this you can enclose the entire body of your handler function with a try-catch.

```
module.exports.handler(event, context, callback) {
  try {
    // Do you what you want to do.
    return callback(null, 'Success')
  } catch (err) {
    // You probably still want to log it.
    console.error(err)
    // Return happy despite all the hardships you went through.
    return callback(null, 'Still success')
  }
}
```

As for failures due to timeouts there are things you can do.

If it times out **outside** of your handler, there's usually something wrong with your code (e.g. incorrect database config, etc) that you should look at.

If it times out **inside** your handler during an invocation, there is something you can do about it.

- If it's an HTTP request, you should set the timeout of the request to be shorter than your Lambda's timeout, this way it will fail properly and you can catch it.
- If it's a database connection, you can probably set a timeout using the library that you're using.
- If it's your logic that times out, you can upgrade the Lambda to use higher memory-CPU to make it faster. You can also check `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()` to know if the Lambda is about to timeout, so you can handle it earlier.

Comment: Thanks for answering @dashmug! In case of time out error, is it catched in the try catch too? Because it is a limitation of AWS Lamda. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, timeout errors can't be caught by this try-catch.

Comment: @dashmug The code within try-catch executes ~5 times slower (js). Still more money for AWS))

Comment: Doing this will prevent you from using the `CloudWatch Metric` for `AWS/Lambda` `Errors`. If you are ok with that, then go for it.

Answer (score 15):

If you call the function asynchronously, in the `Console`, under `Function configuration`, you can modify the `Retry attempts`:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Since [November 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/?nc1=h_ls), it is possible to set the retry count to 0.

That means the lambda will not be retried on error.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned before, this feature has been added lately. To achieve this behaviour using `cloudformation` you will need both an `AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig`:

```yaml
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: my-lambda-dev
      ...

  MyLambdaAsyncConfig:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref MyLambda
      MaximumRetryAttempts: 0
      Qualifier: $LATEST
```

Answer (score 1):

If using python then need to put the code in try/catch block as well however there will be no callback. For example:

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ' + str(e))
```

Since the error has been handled, Lambda will not retry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, I recommend you to follow [this thread](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1104).

If you are using Java, inside `handleRequest` method add this lines:

```java
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setMaxErrorRetry(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to identify and stop retry when there is a failure.

```
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
      let lastReqId;
      if (lastReqId == context.awsRequestId) {
        console.log("Lambda auto retry detected. Aborting");// you can write your own logic to decide what to do with the failure data
        return context.succeed();
      } else {
        console.log("new context");
        lastReqId = context.awsRequestId;
      }
    };
```

you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@meego/disable-auto-retries-in-aws-lambda-4443cb18fde4)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the retry will hit the same container as the previously failed invocation? Because, if not, this logic is doomed to fail... It's safer to push the request ID to external storage, such as DynamoDB.

Comment: Actually, this is absolutely certain to fail. Lambda may retry multiple times, with a period of time between each retry. In the meanwhile, Lambda is likely to be invoked by another request, updating the lastReqId. When the retry comes in, you can't identify it anymore.

Comment: I tried a poc on streams and this worked, based on my analysis  if its stream you are working on and lambda fails it will re-try the failed request and will not take another request. However i see that you have a valid point, As the above might fail in another cases

Comment: Isnt it an option to put the `context.succeed()` in catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by placing the following line of code:

callback(null, "message");

Into my function such as the below update to DynamoDB. When there is an error, rather than retrying for hours on end, this callback outside of the if / else will stop the retries.

```
dynamodb.updateItem(params, function(err, data){
                 if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    callback(err, data)
            } else {
                 console.log(data);
                 callback(null, data);
           }
           callback(null, "message");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just **return true**, for example, if you're invoking a Lambda function, using Node.JS.

I want to stop running the Lambda function, if there's no data.

So I check for an empty object being returned from the API.

If it's empty, I return true, and the Lambda is stopped, and the EventBridge is also not re-tried.

This worked for me.