# How to set retry timeout for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We are using recently released feature from AWS Lambda and SQS integration.
Whenever there is a message in SQS, Lambda is triggered and process the message.

However, In case of Lambda failure, it retires to process the message again.

Is there a way to configure interval between retries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069363/aws-lambda-how-to-stop-retries-when-there-is-a-failure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda - How to stop retries when there is a failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069363/aws-lambda-how-to-stop-retries-when-there-is-a-failure)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no, but to overcome this problem you can put your Lambda inside a state machine (using AWS Step Functions), and using the machine's configuration you can control the retires behavior and even disable retries if you want.

[This blog post](https://medium.com/epsagon/how-to-handle-aws-lambda-errors-like-a-pro-e5455b013d10) I've written gives a more general explanation.