# Disable lambda retries on Kinesis EventSourceMapping

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I want simply to disable lambda retries when it's launched by a kinesis trigger. If the lambda fails or exit, I don't want it to retry.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069363/aws-lambda-how-to-stop-retries-when-there-is-a-failure/49069568#49069568

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It doesn't work when you have async Code ( Api calls ... ).

Answer (score 1):

From [AWS Lambda Retry Behavior - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html):

> Poll-based (or pull model) event sources that are stream-based: These consist of Kinesis Data Streams or DynamoDB. When a Lambda function invocation fails, AWS Lambda attempts to process the erring batch of records until the time the data expires, which can be up to seven days.
>
> The exception is treated as blocking, and AWS Lambda will not read any new records from the shard until the failed batch of records either expires or is processed successfully. This ensures that AWS Lambda processes the stream events in order.

There does not appear to be any configuration options to change this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
So, there is no solution when the lambda retries forever ..

Answer (score 0):

How about handling your error properly so that the invocation will still succeed and Lambda will not retry it anymore?

In NodeJS, it would be something like this...

```
export const handler = (event, context) => {
    return doWhateverAsync()
        .then(() => someSuccessfulValue)
        .catch((err) => {
            // Log the error at least.
            console.log(error)

            // But still return something so Lambda won't retry.
            return someSuccessfulValue
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, javascript errors are not handled such as error while parsing a JSON, reading a non existing property in an object (undefined), these errors will force Lambda to exit directly and will retry forever ...

Comment: @WassimBenAmor, your code has to handle it. If it's not handled, your code is doing it wrong. Those errors are all catch-able if you enclose them in a `try`-`catch` or a `Promise.catch`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Every solution or platform in this world, can have bugs. Even if it's working today, we don't know what can happens tomorrow. A little bug in an Api call or anything can cause very big problems when we have a Lambda retrying forever.
Well finally, I have turned my lambda (Node code) into a little express server in an EC2 instance. I have simultated (The fifo queue of Kinesis in the server, So I don't need Lambda + Kinesis anymore )

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, but the goal of all this is to make lambda works in a fifo queue. Because I have data that can be modified by many lambdas launched in the same time. SQS and SNS don't do it also. Only DynamoDB and KInesis streams can do this whose are expensive. So a simple EC2 instance can simulate the FIFO queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Lambda Event Source Mapping to trigger your Lambda with a batch of records from kinesis stream shard then you can configure the maximum number of retries that will be made by the event source mapping.

another option is to configure the maximum age of the record which is sent to the function.

> Retry attempts – The maximum number of times that Lambda retries when the function returns an error. This doesn't apply to service errors or throttles where the batch didn't reach the function.

> Maximum age of record – The maximum age of a record that Lambda sends to your function.

A good practice is to configure failure destination. this is usually an SQS queue or SNS topic. details of the batch that caused the invocation to fail are stored here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-errors for more info.