# how to limit number of times aws lambda executes on failure?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to Python and AWS.following a tutorial, I created a S3 bucket, when object is created in s3 it triggers following lambda function ( see code below). while testing I found, initially i had some error in my code, so when i uploaded a file , lambda executes then if it threw an error. it tries to execute again and again. I am guessing this is default nature  of lambda function, if it fails it tries to execute it again. I want to add some error handling and may be some logging too. also, if there an error with processing a file, can i limit it so that lambda just executes once and doesn't keep trying.

```
import boto3
import os
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
aws4auth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,credentials.secret_key,region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
                    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

obj = s3.Object(name,key) 

# get the object
response = obj.get()

print(response)
```

Comment: The code you've posted is invalid lambda code. Are you sure you are showing the correct code?

Comment: Already answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069363/aws-lambda-how-to-stop-retries-when-there-is-a-failure) thread. Best of luck on your AWS journey! :)

Answer (score 2):

[S3 invokes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) your function asynchronously:

> Amazon S3 invokes your function **asynchronously** with an event that contains details about the object. The following example shows an event that Amazon S3 sent when a deployment package was uploaded to Amazon S3.

Therefore you can set its retry attempts from defualt 2 to 0:

[image]

Comment: thanks, one way i thought of doing this was to move the file to another bucket so that the lambda doesn't try to process the same file again. but that will probably add more cost read/write to another s3.

Comment: @ozil The primary way of controlling the reties would be the `Retry attempts` options. You can also try moving the file, but if the lambda fails to process it, how can you move it? At the very beginning ?

Comment: thanks again. is there a way i can configure this via cloud formation template?

Comment: @ozil Yes. You can use [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventinvokeconfig.html) in CFN.